# Javascript - Pressing 'Return' Key to run javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, passwords, return

I have a very basic, low level javascript password field on my website. This is operating fine for what I need it for.

The problem I am having though is that the user has to click the enter button to check if the password is correct. What can I enter into my script (and where) to allow users to also have the option to hit the 'return' key to enter there password?

Here is the code I am using, any help on this would be awesome!

```
<input id='password' type='text' />

    <a id='enter' href="_the_bank.html" onclick="javascript:return validatePass()">ENTER</a>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("password").placeholder = "Password";
    function validatePass(){
        if(document.getElementById('password').value == 'Password_01'){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert('Login Incorrect');
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you really compare the user input with correct 'static' password String in your code?

Comment: Use forms, and don't validate the password in JavaScript. There is no situation, ever, _ever_, in which that will end well.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole thing in a form, change the a link to a button type=submit, and change the js so that it sends you to a new page.

```
<form type="submit"><input id='password' type='text' />

<button type="submit" id='enter' href="_the_bank.html" onclick="javascript:return validatePass()">ENTER</button></form>

<script>
document.getElementById("password").placeholder = "Password";
function validatePass(){
    if(document.getElementById('password').value == 'Password_01'){
        window.location.href="_the_bank.html";
    }else{
        //reset the password field or something
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Great, thanks for taking the time to help someone get into javascript. How exactly would I make that particular code send me to a new page? At the moment it doesn't seem to do anything. Thanks